How to test overlapping areas in Godot with GUT
Short Summary
I have been running through my tests and found that I really need to test, through GUT and continuous testing, if the objects that I am creating are able to be overlapped properly. Especially for more complicated drag and drop functionality - Combining Objects and their shapes, etc.
While I can test some of the functionality manually I would like to keep testing through code as much as possible.
Pseudo Code Example
As a basic example - No code:
## test_overlapping_areas
# Create First Area2D
# Create Child CollisionPolygon2D for First Area2D - Set Area

# Create Second Area2D
# Create Child CollisionPolygon2D for Second Area2D - Set Area

# Assert True that area has overlapping areas

While this is a simple draft of what needs to be done, there are still some steps missing for what I need to do.
How am I able to specify the areas that are overlapped?
How am I able to define the space, points, area that they contain?
In summary, how can I create a new area2D with collision shapes to be modified through code that can show that the areas have been overlapped.
What I have done:
I had a look at the PhysicsServer as it looks like I needed to run the _process function to get the overlapping areas to be calculated. I don't need or have a specific _process function.
Is there a way to do this without needing to create an empty _process function?
Each time that I try to incorporate a test the has_overlapping_areas() function, the result remains empty. Still assuming that the _process hasn't been run. Even when I try to run the _process it doesn't allow anything else to be calculated - I'm suspecting because I don't have a _process function created.
I am still unable to trigger the area_entered or area_exited signals. Meaning that I can only manually use the triggered functions within the callable. Which means that I am unable to successfully tell if any previous actions have been able to trigger the signals that are needed.

This example shows how to create Area2Ds in code, and check if they are colliding.
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    var area1 = Area2D.new()
    var area2 = Area2D.new()
    var collision_shape1 = CollisionShape2D.new()
    var collision_shape2 = CollisionShape2D.new()
    var shape = CircleShape2D.new()
    
    shape.set_radius(20)
    
    collision_shape1.set_shape(shape)
    
    collision_shape2.set_shape(shape)
    
    area1.add_child(collision_shape1)
    area1.set_position(Vector2(-15, 0))
    
    area2.add_child(collision_shape2)
    area2.set_position(Vector2(15,0))
    
    add_child(area1)
    add_child(area2)

var frames = 0
func _physics_process(delta):
    if frames < 5:
        print("collision=", get_child(0).has_overlapping_areas(), " on frame ", frames)
    frames += 1


If you want to check the collisions of newly created objects, make sure both colliders have been added as a child in the scene tree for at least 1 physics frame.
